# Adding Command Line Arguments to shortcut with .bat file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to add command line arguments after created a shortcut in a .bat file. Here is my code:

```
@echo off

set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\dny.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\deney\zf.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%

cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```

I want to add this: /server xxx.xxx.net

After all I should see this on shortcut path:

C:\Users\Username\Desktop\dny\zf.exe /server xxx.xxx.net

Comment: Take a look at this: [.CreateShortcut](https://ss64.com/vb/shortcut.html); yo may find a suitable property called `Arguments`...

Comment: also see [create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/admin-development/create-desktop-shortcut-with-wsh)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by adding this between targetpath and save commands:

```
echo oLink.Arguments = "/server xxx.xxx.net" >> %SCRIPT%
```